# Kafka Stream Consumer Group not showing offset

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I have two kafka streams applications.

I can see there consumer groups using:

```
>bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh  --list --bootstrap-server localhost:9092`
streams-distribution-app
streams-collection-app
```

I can see offsets of the distribution-app using:

```
>bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --group streams-distribution-app
TOPIC                    PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID                             HOST            CLIENT-ID
o365_user_activity       0          3900            3985            85              streams-distribution-app-StreamThread-1 /127.0.0.1      
o365_cassandra_data_load 0          -               0               -               streams-distribution-app-StreamThread-1 /127.0.0.1      streams-distribution-app
```

But I cant view the offsets for collection-app:

```
bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --group streams-collection-app 
Note: This will not show information about old Zookeeper-based consumers.
```

The app is running and processing logs. I dont understand what can be the reason for not describing the offset information.

**UPDATE:**

After quite some time (around 20 mins) I can finally see the offsets.
But there is a lot of lag.

```
bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --group streams-collection-app 
Note: This will not show information about old Zookeeper-based consumers.

TOPIC                    PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG     CONSUMER-ID                             HOST        CLIENT-ID
o365_activity_contenturl 0          200             64941           64741   streams-collection-app-StreamThread-1   /127.0.0.1 streams-collection-app
```

These are the configs for stream-collection-app:

```
props.put(StreamsConfig.producerPrefix(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG), Integer.MAX_VALUE);
props.put(StreamsConfig.producerPrefix(ProducerConfig.RETRY_BACKOFF_MS_CONFIG), Integer.MAX_VALUE);
props.put(StreamsConfig.producerPrefix(ProducerConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG), Integer.MAX_VALUE);
props.put(StreamsConfig.consumerPrefix(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG), 200);
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I tried increasing the `num.stream.threads` config and set it 4. And again restarted the application with some 40k+ records on source topic.

Still there was no output on describing the stream app consumer-group. After about 10-15 mins I can see the following offsets:

```
bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --group streams-collection-app
Note: This will not show information about old Zookeeper-based consumers.

TOPIC                    PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG    CONSUMER-ID                            HOST            CLIENT-ID
o365_activity_contenturl 0          200             11274           11074  streams-collection-app-StreamThread-1  /127.0.0.1      streams-app-StreamThread-1
o365_activity_contenturl 1          200             11384           11184  streams-collection-app-StreamThread-2  /127.0.0.1      streams-app-StreamThread-2
o365_activity_contenturl 3          200             11343           11143  streams-collection-app-StreamThread-4  /127.0.0.1      streams-app-StreamThread-4
o365_activity_contenturl 2          200             11471           11271  streams-collection-app-StreamThread-3  /127.0.0.1      streams-app-StreamThread-3
```

Comment: do you have access to your consumers logs? Do you know how much does it take to process one message? Does it finish processing and commit offset?

Comment: Yes I have access to logs, The processing of one message is completed by sending a remote call and receiving some data. The logs show that the messages are being processed continuously.

Comment: It seems, that your application is just slow. You should try to investigate the root cause and how long it take to process a single message (`peek()` might be your friend)